# Minimum in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, min

I have python Dict, when I am using `min()`. See my code

```
scores = {leaf_size: round(get_mae(leaf_size, train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y)) for leaf_size in candidate_max_leaf_nodes}
best_tree_size = min(scores, key=scores.get)
```

get_mae() is just a function for calculating mean absolute error.

but it shows following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-aa5b1fc6e492> in <module>
      8 # print(dict)
      9 scores = {leaf_size: round(get_mae(leaf_size, train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y)) for leaf_size in candidate_max_leaf_nodes}
---> 10 best_tree_size = min(scores, key=scores.get)
     11 # list = scores.items()
     TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that you've used *min* as a variable and have shadowed the built-function.

Try this:

```
best_tree_size = __builtins__.min(scores, key=scores.get)
```

That will use the actual *min()* function rather than the *min* variable that references the *int* value.